# ASP.NET changing controls order in div

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two controls in div wrapped into update panel. My code requires for user to be able to change position of second control left,top,right,bottom from first controls point of view. I was thinking of adding a MultiView and adding 4 Views but controls can't have same ID in views and that is essential for my code functionality.

What would be best approach here?

Comment: I have read somewhere that VS doesn't allow same IDs even in MV views but I will give it a try.

Comment: Yes, i don't think that's possible to use the same ID in a MultiView since its not templated like GridView,FormView etc. But couldn't you change your functionality that it returns always the correct control according to the ActiveViewIndex?

Comment: @Tim Probably but that seems to me more like hack and possible exception generating hole. I hoped there is better solution for this.If there is not other solution I will be forced to do that.

Comment: Probably the best would be not to use the MultiView but to control position and layout via CSS(4 different classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the second control into a placeholder control. See this question : [How can you move ASP.Net controls to different places on the Web form at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714046/how-can-you-move-asp-net-controls-to-different-places-on-the-web-form-at-runtime)