# How to move panel inside code while rendering

Tags: asp.net, render

I have a code that used to looks like :

```
<asp:Panel id="TopPanel"> Some Content 1</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel id="MiddlePanel"> Some Content 2</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel id="BottomPanel"> Some Content 3</asp:Panel>
```

After a new change request, I want that for a new version the code the panels to render like

```
<asp:Panel id="BottomPanel"> Some Content 3</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel id="MiddlePanel"> Some Content 2</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel id="TopPanel"> Some Content 1</asp:Panel>
```

Is there a way apart from copy-paste of same code that will work in this case?

So that for version 1 the code will appear as

```
<asp:Panel id="TopPanel"> Some Content 1</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel id="MiddlePanel"> Some Content 2</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel id="BottomPanel"> Some Content 3</asp:Panel>
```

and for version 2 it will appear as

```
<asp:Panel id="BottomPanel"> Some Content 3</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel id="MiddlePanel"> Some Content 2</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel id="TopPanel"> Some Content 1</asp:Panel>
```

I am using asp.net,C#.

Also note that Some Content in my case can contain any control - asp as well as userCustomControl, update panels and labels in listview.

I have already tried a

```
 protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            if (true)
            {

                StringBuilder Staticsb = new StringBuilder();
                StringWriter Statictw = new StringWriter(Staticsb);
                HtmlTextWriter statichw = new HtmlTextWriter(Statictw);
                Panel Panel1Sample= new Panel();
                Panel1Sample= Panel1;
                Panel1Sample.RenderControl(statichw);
                LiteralPanel1.Text = Staticsb.ToString();

            }
            else
            {
                base.Render(writer);
            }
        }
```

But it crashes due to update panels

Comment: I don't quite follow, if you are asked to change the order of the controls, why not just change them? What do you mean by version 1 and 2, do you need to run two versions of the same program at the same time? If you do just use git or other version control system to track all changes and publish the correct version when needed.

Comment: Its a run time code - it has two versions - it is not related to git version - it is live code whose UI I am changing by introducing a new version, if the user will open old code he will see the old UI when he opens new version he will see new UI

Comment: Ok, have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714046/how-can-you-move-asp-net-controls-to-different-places-on-the-web-form-at-runtime

Comment: It gives error Cannot unregister UpdatePanel with ID 'UpdatePanel1' since it was not registered with the ScriptManager. This might occur if the UpdatePanel was removed from the control tree and later added again, which is not supported. - will check if it works